# Posting times do not agree in chat rooms

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, time

I recently saw this in [wordbuilders general chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat):

[image: timebug].

Basically, a message posted and stared more than 9 hours ago shows up as posted 8 hours ago in the sidebar. I suspect it is an issue about the list do not update that often. However, it persisted in refresh for up to now when I post this (20 min after), indicating that those times can be wrong for at least 1/3 of the time.

The delay between updates seems way too long, especially compared to the delay of only a few seconds to respond to staring events. Does it really take that much capacity to update the chat sidebar times more often than >20 minutes?

Comment: I would be surprised if the answer isn't only *blame caching* but also [tag:status-bydesign]. The star-board is not the most important I guess.